# How do I fix my application from leaking when using Qt 4.5?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, qt

Without any changes to my code except building against Qt 4.5 I get the following warning message when I run my application:

```
*** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x50a1b0 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with
no pool in place - just leaking
```

I am not using any Objective-C in my code but Qt 4.5 is using a new Cocoa based back end instead of Carbon.

I am not sure how to address and fix this error message. Anyone have a clue?

Comment: I found out what was the cause of the leak error message. I had a program call Fantasktik installed and running. This program hooks itself into all running programs. I guess some code from Fantasktik was getting run before Qt had setup the NSAutoreleasePool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, when you see this problem in your code, you bracket the offending code block with `NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];` before and `[pool release];` after.  You can set a breakpoint on the `_NSAutoreleaseNoPool` function and just look up the stack crawl to see what the offending code is.  Keep in mind that `-autorelease` is used everywhere in Cocoa, so it might not be a specific call to autorelease in Qt's code that's triggering it.

However, since this is Qt's code that's doing this, and, last I checked, Qt/Cocoa was still very much a work in progress, you should probably just submit a bug report with the error and a stack crawl to them, and wait for them to fix it.

Comment: I thought it was `[pool drain]`.